# How to install bigger sqlite db, as a reward for installing my other app?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a quiz game, with around 2000 questions, in imported in assets folder sqlite database. My game is free. I have another quiz also. Is there a way to place a button in my quiz with a link to my other quiz game on google play, and after a user install my other game, to somehow install another sqlite database with additional 1000 questions, as a reward for installing my other app? I saw something like this in another games, with coins and stuff. I don't know if I explained this right way. :)

Comment: use two assets db's. Check at app start from app1 if app2 is installed if yes write note in preferences. Then you can open the small or big database with checking the Preference entry.

Comment: OK, I know how to check if the app is installed, but can you help me with the Preference part? How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit(); 
                        editor.putBoolean("proversion", true);
                        editor.commit();
```

Read:

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean proversion= settings.getBoolean("proversion", false);
```

Now you can work with the boolean

```
 if (proversion) {
// pro Version DB
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks.I hope it does. :)